# parse an XML with SimpleXML which has multiple namespaces

Tags: php, soap, namespaces, simplexml

I have this ugly XML which has alot of namespaces on it, when I try to load it with simpleXML if i indicate the first namespace I'd get an xml object ,but following tags with other namespaces would not make it to the object.

How can I parse this XML ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">wscompany.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">mysite.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>something</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>moredata.com</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="compXML">theservice</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>theaction</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>a certain messageid</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2009-04-11T18:43:58</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>mid:areference</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">an impresive binary security toekn</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <SessionCreateRS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11" version="1" status="Approved">
            <ConversationId>the goodbye token</ConversationId>
        </SessionCreateRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

im trying to parse it with the following code

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($res,NULL,NULL,"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
?>
```

but the $xml object would only contain the following

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [Body] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you need to register the namespacing and access with XPath.  Something like the following should get you going (I haven't the facility to test this).

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($res, NULL, NULL, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap-env', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('eb', 'http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('wsse', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext');
```

Then you can do something like:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//eb:MessageHeader') as $header)
{
    var_export($header->xpath('//eb:CPAId')); // Should output 'something'.
}
```

You may not need to register the namespacing, thinking about it, as they are alredy present in the XML.  Not sure on this though, would need to test.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Simply brillian you not only helped me solve my problem but also clarified how xpath worked :)

thanks !

Comment: There is no need to switch to XPath just because you are using namespaces.

Comment: If you are using XPath, then you do need to register the namespaces explicitly as in your code above, otherwise failure occurs.

Comment: i have used exactly what you have suggested with exact copy on input mentioned in question but still i am getting `array ( 0 => SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array( )), )` this kind of result. I cant understand why. Can you please explain?

Comment: Thank you! I've always been confused by this

Comment: thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 12):

1) Do not use `print_r` and friends to see what is "in" a SimpleXML object. See https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug for explanation and alternatives.

2) Namespace support in SimpleXML is provided by the [`->children()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) and [`->attributes()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) methods.

For example you could get the PartyId of the From node like this:

```
$from_party = (string)$xml->children('soap-env', true)->Header->children('eb', true)->MessageHeader->From->PartyId;
```

Comment: This was the most useful comment for me, good that you point out that print_r etc don't work and provide a link to simplexml_debug, props!

Comment: Those Debug functions are really helpful for people who are new to this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that comes across this I scratched my head trying to return the correct data and although the top answer was extremely close it still took me a while to find the answer. Eventually used this page to help: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_registerxpathnamespace.asp

I believe the for loop can directly access what you need. i.e.

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//eb:CPAId') as $header)
{
    echo $header; // Should output 'something'.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's a soap-envelope. You might want to use a soap-client to abstract all the xml-parsing away. PHP [comes with a rather good soap-client](http://www.php.net/soap) included as default.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
   $soap_url = 'http://path/wsdl/somefile.wsdl';
   $soap_client = new SoapClient($soap_url);

   var_dump($soap_client->__getFunctions());
```

For more detail [read here](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)