# SOAP response to XML with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

I am trying  to convert a SOAP response to XML.

SOAP has an envelop and a body

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
```

When I try to convert

```
$responseXML = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

I get

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#20 (0) { }
```

If I edit the `$string` as `soap:Envelope` and `soap:Body` I can get the XML.

What's wrong with `:`? Can not get XML.

I hope it's clear. Anyone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A SOAP message *is* already XML. The problem is that it has namespaces so you have to access it differently. (The part before the colon is the identifier for the namespace.)

[Here (google cached copy)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:40v20W7sUxkJ:www.sitepoint.com/simplexml-and-namespaces/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk) is an example of using namespaces with SimpleXML.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740730/parse-an-xml-with-simplexml-which-has-multiple-namespaces) is a specific example for reading SOAP messages.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML requires special treatment for namespaced XML ([ref.](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/10/20/simplexml-and-namespaces/))

Comment: Totally clear.But what about if i want to access for example xml->soap:Envelop->soap:Body->item1->item2

Comment: because "soap:" is not tied to a namespace in this example. mind that not the namespace prefix must match, but the namespace itself.