# Can't get data from XML with namespaces

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I make a soap request and I get the following response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://*************/******/****" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://*************/******/****/***">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GetEventV2Response>
      <ns1:GetEventV2Result>
       <ns1:Events>
         <ns1:Event>
           <ns1:Id>147624</ns1:Id>
           <ns1:Name>Rockstars</ns1:Name>
         <ns1:Genre>
         ...
```

I have tried to get the element ID inside of `<ns1:Event>`, but the code bellow doesn't work and don't know why. I searched and tried a fews solutions but without success.

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
  ....
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  x = new SimpleXmlElement($response);
  foreach($x->xpath('//ns1:Event') as $event) {
      var_export($event->xpath('ns1:Id'));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try this?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
foreach ($xml->xpath('//ns1:Event') as $item)
{
    print_r($item);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: Also not work. I have a doubt: It's normal in my php file print a string in variable `$response` if I don't set header to `header("Content-type: text/xml");`?

Comment: take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773497/soap-response-to-xml-with-simplexml

Answer (score 1):

Use [**SimpleXMLElement::registerXPathNamespace**](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) to register the namespace.  For example:

```
$x->registerXPathNamespace('ns1', 'http://*************/******/****');
```

and, later:

```
$event->registerXPathNamespace('ns1', 'http://*************/******/****');
```

Comment: I follow your suggestion but still doesn't work, I receive the following error: `this page contains the following erros: error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty.    Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.` :/

Comment: Did you register the namespace for both `$x` and `$event`?

Comment: yes inside the loop for I put this: `$event->registerXPathNamespace('Event', 'http://*************/******/****');` only if I'm doing wrong

Comment: The first argument to `registerXPathNamespace()` should be the namespace prefix, `'ns1'`.

Comment: I make an `echo $x` and don´t print anything, which is strange because the variable `$response` have the content of result :/