# PHP parse with DOM (no results)

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

I am trying to retreive the body text located in this span class attribute.

```
<span id="" style="color:#525B64;">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</span>
```

I tested it on my web server and I get no errors but the page is blank. I'm very new to this so I do not know where to go from here.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
// Load remote file, supress parse errors
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://somewebpage.com');
libxml_clear_errors();

// use XPath to find all nodes with a class attribute of header
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
$nodes = $xp->query('//span[@class="msgBody"]');

// output first item's content
echo $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
?>
```

Comment: What's the actual page you're trying to access? As far as I can tell, this code works.

Answer (score 3):

Everything seems fine in this code.

What I'd try to do is:

- remove the line which supresses parse errors.
- load the remote file with `file_get_contents` to see if it loads properly
- query document with XPath like `//*` and loop over resulting `DOMNodeList` (with foreach) to see if the tree is built correctly.

Btw. to surpress parse errors reported by `->loadHTMLFile()` method I use `@` operator.

Comment: Personally, to suppress parse errors reported by loadHTMLFile(), I fix the errors. ;-)

Comment: Well, that's a fair statement. Thanks for raining on my parade.

Comment: BTW, +1 for considering that `allow_url_fopen` may be turned off, disallowing the code from loading a remote file URL.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM creates nodes for everthing: attributes, text, comments, elements, you name it. So you're not after the value of the span node even though it might seem that way, you actually want to get the TextNode inside of the span and get *its* value instead. Try something like:

```
echo $nodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue
```

You can also get this directly from the xpath query:

```
$nodes = $xp->query('//span[@class="msgBody"]/text()');
```

(Though I've never had much luck with xpath, personally.)

Comment: I tried this and got the following error "Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object"

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is only one `span` element with this class in the document you are parsing?

Maybe `->item(0)` returns empty element and the desired element is next on the list?

Comment: <span id="ctl00_ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_LayoutContent1_messagesId_JSmsgInfo_msgTextBody" class="msgBody" style="color:#525B64;"></span>
 <-- This span is empty so the page is blank! Everything is correct!

Answer (score 1):

**Very often such behavior is due to a default namespace** (check to see if there is something similar to this: `xmlhs="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`).

Using in XPath expressions element names that are in default namespace, is the most FAQ in the xpath tag -- just search for "*xpath default namespace*" to find many good answers.

Comment: @PeterSmith yes there is this <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

Comment: @Dan: For example how to register namespaces in PHP (this solves the default namespace issue) see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864359/using-xpath-on-a-php-simplexml-object-soap-namespaces-not-working