# Convert SOAP response to associative array using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How do I convert SOAP response like this to php array using SimpleXML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <eWAYHeader xmlns="http://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/manageRebill">
      <eWAYCustomerID>9******5</eWAYCustomerID>
      <Username>ac****@si****.com.sand</Username>
      <Password>*******</Password>
    </eWAYHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateRebillCustomerResponse xmlns="http://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/manageRebill">
      <CreateRebillCustomerResult>
        <Result>Success</Result>
        <ErrorSeverity />
        <ErrorDetails />
        <RebillCustomerID>60066328</RebillCustomerID>
      </CreateRebillCustomerResult>
    </CreateRebillCustomerResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you got this and what you intend to do with it, cause i smell a bad case of "Not using technologies correctly" here

Comment: I'm developing a application using Eway payment gateway API. I'm getting this after I send SOAP request using CURL in php. This is come as response.

Comment: @AchinthaSamindika, any reason you want it to be associative array? The SOAP response you get can be pretty easily parsed/traversed with XPath (see some good point [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/740795/155033)), also using [SOAP extension](http://php.net/soap) seems a better choice.

Comment: I'm newbie and still not got how to traverse. If you can it in using this xml it will great help. Thanks

Comment: @AchinthaSamindika, loork a bit within linker/related questions in the right sidebar and you'll figure way how to do it ;)

Comment: Please can someone show me how to extract 

<Result>Success</Result>
<RebillCustomerID>60066328</RebillCustomerID>

Now this is my second day, I'm newbie to SOAP and very hard to find how to do it. Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at [SoapClient](http://php.net/soapclient) class then? It'll save HEAPS of trouble.