# PHP traversing dbpedia xml

Tags: php, namespaces, xml-parsing, dbpedia

I need to traverse a dbpedia's xml resource file to get the abstract and some other basic information like formation year and budget.

An example for this would be the [US EPA](http://dbpedia.org/page/United_States_Environmental_Protection_Agency).(the bottom of the page has links to different data formats of the same file)

I only need the first rdf:Description namespace of the xml file. A snippet of the code

```
$xml_result = file_get_contents($xml_url);
$xml_data = simplexml_load_string($xml_result);
$namespaces = $xml_data->getNamespaces(true);
//print_r($namespaces);

$current = $xml_data->children($namespaces['rdf']);
```

This only gets me the rdf elements inside the first rdf:Description. how do i get access to other elements like the dbpedia-owl namespace elements inside the Description element ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple namespaces, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13350242/865201

Without testing it, I think you can use something like

```
$xml_data->children($namespaces['rdf'])->Description->children($namespaces['dbpedia-owl'])->anotherElement;
```