# Simplexml_load_file() cant get it working cause of 2 name paths

Tags: php, xml, object, simplexml

I have a really complicated XML file(in my opinion). It contains multiple namespaces(prefixes) and I am trying to convert it to an object.

So at first we were using this function

```
simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
```

file.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animal:race>
    <animal:dog>
        <specification:color>Black</specification>
    </animal:dog>
    <animal:cat>
        <animal:name>Flappie</animal:name>
    </animal:cat>
</animal:race>
```

At first the function returned an empty object.
Then we found out that you have to specify prefixes like this:

```
   simplexml_load_file("file.xml",null,null,"animal");
```

This returned an object but without all the other prefixes like: specification.
So the object became:(outputted as an array

```
object(animal:race)#1 (2) { 
    ["dog"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) { 
    }
    ["cat"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { 
        [animal:name] => string "flappie"
    }
}
```

So my conclusion is that we need our other namespaces to be "included" to.. cause specifications arent shown.

Comment: Have you tried registering the different namespaces? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740730/parse-an-xml-with-simplexml-which-has-multiple-namespaces and using XPath to iterate your object.

Comment: @R.Chappell We've seen that but we cant figure out how to make it work.

Comment: @R.Chappell Do we just need registerxnamespace rules? cause after we've done that it still didnt work. 

and how does that foreach loop work..

Comment: The registerXPathNamespace allows you to find nodes using XPath, which is like jQuery selectors for XML but a bit more complicated. What are you trying to do with the file, do you just want to build up an array using the XML described?

Comment: @R.Chappell 
So I am using soapclient in php and the method needs an object which is created from the xml message.. but the xml has prefixes/namespaces which complicates using the simplexml_load_file function cuase ti doesnt include those with prefixes.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using PHP Dom instead as it has far better support for documents with multiple namespaces. http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php would be a good start

Comment: @R.Chappell Yeah but then the content is not an object.. right?

Comment: No, it is an object. It's a DomDocument which should be supported by SoapClient.

Comment: @R.Chappell
$xml = new DOMDocument(1.0, 'UTF-8');
$xml->load('filename.xml');

dump($xml); die;
 the values are here:
["textContent"]=> string(203)"Lv01 C3 king StUF Yelp King Romain 20161003142300 ZAK 1 false 570000001 570000001"